# Iterator over Chronicle Queue implementation

Tags: chronicle-queue

I'm looking to implement an Iterator<> on a ChronicleQueue `methodReader` (or `tailer` if this cant be done with a `methodReader`).

Is there a way to see if a queue has more data ( can I use `lastReadIndex()` < ??? ) (so I can implement the `hasNext()` of the `Iterator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the next excerpt to see if one exists, hasNext() can return true if it finds one, and next() can return the message you last read.